# unordered_map::emplace() и конструктор класса с параметрами

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Есть класс:

```
    class Result {
    private:
        int     a,
                b;
    public:
        Result ();
        Result (int &, int &);
    };

    Result::Result(int &a_, int &b_) {
        a = a_;
        b = b_*2;
    };
```

добавить объект этого класса в vector используя конструктор с параметрами можно так:

```
    vector <Result> vectResult;
    vectResult.emplace_back(2,2);
```

не могу понять как добавить объект этого класса в unordered_map с помощью emplace()

```
    unordered_map <int, Result> mapResult;
    int key(111);
    mapResult.emplace(key,(2,2)); // тут я незнаю синтаксиса, поэтому получаю ошибку
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом заметим, что конструктор Result у вас принимает неконстантные ссылки, поэтому передать туда константы напрямую не получится. Надо создать вспомогательные локальные переменные:

```
   int a = 2;
   int b = 2;
```

Параметры у `emplace` могут быть такими же, как у [конструкторов](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) `std::pair<int, Result>`. Один вариант:

```
mapResult.emplace(111, Result(a, b));
```

другой:

```
mapResult.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                  std::make_tuple(111),
                  std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b)));
```

---

Как мне кажется, в вашем случае нет нужды передавать параметры в конструктор Result по ссылке (особенно неконстантной), можно ограничиться передачей по значению:

```
class Result {
    private:
        int a, b;
    public:
        Result (int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

В этом случае вспомогательные переменные станут не нужны и код будет попроще. Либо:

```
mapResult.emplace(111, Result(2, 2));
```

либо:

```
mapResult.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                  std::make_tuple(111),
                  std::make_tuple(2, 2));
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, как здесь работает std::make_tuple

Comment: @Cerbo, в каком смысле? make_tuple оборачивает переданные аргументы в tuple.

Comment: @dzioev В прямом смысле. Нужно расписать вариант с std::make_tuple более подробно потому как если ТС спрашивает про emplace велика вероятность, что он и про std::make_tuple мало что знает

Comment: @Cerbo, это выходит за рамки поставленного вопроса (о методе unordered_map::emplace).

Comment: Как же выходит? Ведь вопрос, фактически, про то как неявно вызвать конструктор с параметрами.

Comment: @Cerbo, основная мысль ответа -- метод `unordered_map<Key, Value>::emplace` может принимает те же параметры, что и конструкторы `std::pair<Key, Value>`. Остальное можно прочитать в документации.